# Getting an Error "image source error at React Native"

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm fetching data from web API service from react native ios project, and I got this message

> The RCTURLRequestHandlers RCTDataRequestHandler: 0x7a11c0e0 and RCTImageStoreManager: 0x7a6c46a0 both reported that they can handle the request NSURLRequest: 0x7a28bb10 { URL: %250D%250A%250D%250Ahttps://webApiURL/post1.png }, and have equal priority (0). This could result in non-deterministic behavior.

How can I resolve this issue?

I assigned the Image source this way

```
<Image source={{uri: post.ImagePath}} />
```

And when I tried to remove "uri"

```
<Image source={post.ImagePath} />
```

I got a warning message

> "Warning: Failed propType: Invalid prop `source` supplied to `Image`. Check the render method of `StaticRenderer`."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the `%250D%250A%250D%250A`part of the `post.ImagePath` should not be there.

Could you show the contents of your `post` object?

Comment: yes, thank you that was extra spaces in database field, after removing them, issue disappeared.